# Rollup Postcss don't extract CSS

Tags: vite, postcss

Is there a way to *not* extract CSS files with rollup?

Current:

```
|-assets
|--main.css
|--main.js
```

Desired:

```
|-assets
|--main.js
```

Where main.js imports css. I see this working with Vite client where the main js entry file imports CSS and it works in the browser. It's not obvious to me how but I'm wondering if this is an option.